# IF statement using Dcount

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, vba, dcount

Access complains *"Data Type Mismatch in criteria expression"* with this code ...

`If DCount("[Serial Number]", "INVENTORY OVERVIEW", "[Serial Number] =" & Val(txtSERIAL)) > 1 Then`

Serial Number is the field I'm trying to count.
INVENTORY OVERVIEW is the table where I am trying to do the count.
txtSerial is the text box on a userform.

The objective of this if statement is to determine if there are more than one of the same serial number, and report to the user when they submit a new entry if that serial number already exists within the recordset.

Comment: OHHH THE ERROR IM GETTING IS....

Data Type Mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: OH SORRY AGAIN, I'm a first time poster, I'm using Microsoft Access

Comment: What is the datatype of your *Serial Number* field?

Answer (score -1):

you have to add the quotes to the txt object. So:
"[Serial Number] ='" & Val(txtSERIAL) & "'")) > 1